# Google Maps API Depreciation Time

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We are planning to use data like this to find county from coordinates. Will Google shutdown looks up like this anytime soon?

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=39.76144296429947,-104.8011589050293&sensor=false

I'm not sure if this is coming from V2 or v3 of their APIs.

According to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

you do need and API key

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=API_KEY

however without one it still works

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452

Answer (score 0):

You already use V3, the URL for V2 was http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/geo

related  to the parameters:

- `key` is supported, but not required. But you better use a key, otherwise you will share  your quota with all domains that share the same IP and may often get a `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`
- `sensor` is no longer required(you may omit it)